# Entity Framework: Why DbSet<T> Loads all data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I got little confused with following scenario,

1. I have model 'Student'
2. I have SchoolContext class - public property DbSet Students{get;set;}
3. Service, with following line of code

   ```
   using(var context = new SchoolContext())
   {
       var query = context.Students.Where(s => s.Gender =="M");
       var results = query.ToList();
   }
   ```

While debugging, I mouse hover on `context.Students` & expand property `Results View` and realized all students are already loaded irrespective of filter and after filter-where is getting applied.

I am not sure, however, I read somewhere that until pointer hits `.ToList()` everything remains under `IQueryable`. So here in this case `var query` supposed to be `IQueryable` without loading any data and just query with where condition and next line then will hit database with generated query and return only needed data.

Am I missing anything or mixing it with any other concept of EF?

Comment: Probably because the debugger caused it to execute

Comment: Your attached debugger is enumerating `Students` when you hovered over the property, in production this would not happen.

Comment: Do you mean, in actual scenario, it generates query and then loads data? Is it only causing because of debugging?

Comment: "expand property Results View and realized all students are already loaded irrespective of filter and after filter-where is getting applied" and you completely ignored the warning saying enumerable will be expanded on click lol. If you hovered over query and did the same results would be filtered. Here you are hovering over the entire unfiltered collection (Students)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mouse over on `context.Students` and opening `Results View` force data loading from database to memory (it's needed to show you these data in debugger).
So, only your mouse over is the reason.
In production data will filter as expected.

Comment: That's incorrect. Only when you step into the `Results View` it will execute the query.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes, you are right, I missed it. Added to answer

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, you are right, I edited my question which actually relate what you say.

Comment: @AviKenjale now the question makes more sense. Take it as a Visual Studio feature, not as a bug in your code. You can even use the Immediate Window to run custom queries without running your actual code ;)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, is there a way to see generated SQL somewhere under `IQueryable` object.

Comment: @AviKenjale if you are using Entity Framework Core, then no, only using some SQL Profiler (like the one SQL Server offers).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Yes, unfortunately its EFCore. How about in non-core app?

Comment: @AviKenjale you'd need to switch to Entity Framework 6, there are ways to see the underlying SQL there.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Got this working for Entity Framework Core,
 [UnderlyingSQL](https://gist.github.com/tonysneed/4cac4f4dae2b22e45ec4)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is loading all students for you when you are trying to see the value of non-filtered `Students` property in the debugger:

> While debugging, I mouse hover on context.Students & expand property Results View

Everything remains under IQueryable until you try to evaluate it. It can happen when you call some method which executes query and performs a database roundtrip - `ToList()`, `Count()` etc. Or it can happen when you try to enumerate values in Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: That's incorrect. Only when you step into the `Results View` it will execute the query.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that is exactly what I wrote: *when you are trying to see the value*